# Regex pattern - couples' names

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex pattern that matches patterns like "Jane and John Smith" (I mean first-name and first-name last-name) in the middle of a text. It should not match "Jane Smith and John Smith".

Then I want to substitute all found "Jane and John Smith"s with "Jane Smith and John Smith" by name. I mean any word that matches `[A-Z][a-z]+`.

I wrote this:

```
r'([A-Z][a-z]+)\s+and\s+([A-Z][a-z]+)\s+([A-Z][a-z]+)'
```

but this also matches "Jane Smith and John Smith". I do not know how to exclude "two words" before "and". I am using python.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please define what is a name and what is not. But first read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: that doesnt match "Jane Smith and John Smith" ... it matches "Smith and John Smith" ... use re.match instead of search and that would not match

Comment: thank you for your comment @trincot. I have edited my question. Could you please take another look at it? Thanks.

Comment: thank you @JoranBeasley for your comment. yes, you are right. but I mean, because "Jane Smith and John Smith" has two words before "and", I don't want this to be considered as a match. and I do not want to use re.match because this can be in the middle of the text.

Comment: "Love Jane and John Smith" also has two words before "and". What will you decide? That "Jane" is the name or that "Love Jane" is the (full) name? On which grounds?

Comment: "If John and Jane Smith would like, we can all go to disneyland next weekend."  your regex solves the problem as defined... if you want a better solution you will need to further define your problem space

Comment: @trincot I understand what you mentioned and I agree with that. but I somehow narrowed down my problem to this case. what is the regex that accepts one word before "and" but does not accept two words before "and"

Comment: @JoranBeasley I understand what you mentioned and I agree with that. but I somehow narrowed down my problem to this case. what is the regex that accepts one word before "and" but does not accept two words before "and"

Comment: In the question you wrote you want to find names in the middle of text. How can that be when you don't want two words before 'and'?

Comment: Did you mean to disallow if the first word in your regex equals the last word? Something like this using [capture and backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html): [`([A-Z][a-z]+)\s+and\s+([A-Z][a-z]+)\s+(?!\1\b)([A-Z][a-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/9Y6qeX/3)

Answer (score 1):

As @trincot suggested, you should first understand all the possible shapes that names can have.

By the way, assuming the example you provided, I tried to come up with a regex for cases with "[one single firstname] and [one single firstname] [one single lastname]".

**Proposed solution**

I think you are looking for a look-behind approach, however it turns that look-behind/after do not accept + or * operators.
By using a negative look-behind for titled words not preceeded by dot OR a positive look-behind for titled words preceeded by dot+space I think the problem is resolved.

In other words:

- it matches ". But Jane and John Smith"
- it does not match ".But..." OR "Jane Smith and John Smith".

```
((?<=\.\s[A-Za-z])|(?<![A-Za-z]))[a-z]+\s([A-Z]\w+)\sand\s([A-Z][a-z]+)\s([A-Z][a-z]+)
```

Does this solve your problem? Please let me know.

**Disclaimer**

I gave you an examplified answer for you examplified question (i.e., on simple "[one single firstname] and [one single firstname] [one single lastname]" pattern), follow @trincot comment for good generalized results.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "Jane and John Smith something else  Mary Schmidt and Bill Schmidt"

# first find 4 words strings:  ['Jane and John Smith ', 'Schmidt and Bill Schmidt']
lst = re.findall(r'[A-Z]\w+\s+and\s+[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]\w+\s*',s)

# then make substitution if the first word and the last word do not match
for it in lst:
        lst = it.split()
        word1 = lst[0] 
        word2 = lst[-1:].pop()
        if  word1 == word2:
            continue
        else:
            print(re.sub(fr'({word1})', rf'\1 {word2}',s))

# Jane Smith and John Smith something else  Mary Schmidt and Bill Schmidt
```